# Length of inverse-matrix vector product.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Assume that I have an invertible matrix $A$ and a vector $v$. Let $\|Av\| = k$. Can we deduce the value of $\|A^{-1}v\|$? My guts tell me that $\|A^{-1}v\|$ = $\frac{1}{k}$, but I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: Why do you mean by deduce? Do you mean knowing **only** $k$ to deduce the value of $\|A^{-1}v\|$?

Comment: @copper.hat I don't think it suggests that the hypothesis is true. I selected it because it lets me deduce the simplest example to disprove my hypothesis: Choose $A$ to be the identity matrix, and let $v$ be an arbitrary vector s.t. $\|v\| \neq 1$. However, I do see that it doesn't directly provide a counterexample. I'm not very familiar with the conventions on this site for choosing the best answer -- should I choose the answer that directly gives a counterexample?

Comment: Oops, ignore my now deleted comment. For some reason I had it in my head that $v$ was a unit vector.

Comment: Coincidentally, I actually meant to pose the question with the requirement that $v$ is a unit vector, but forgot to mention it :) However, a quick experiment in MATLAB convinced that the hypothesis doesn't hold in that case either. I probably should've tried that earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the identity matrix for example.  You would have $\|v\|=k$ and your gut feeling would tell you $\|v\|=1/k$.

$k$ and $1/k$ are not equal (in general).

Another example would be a rotation matrix, this won't change the length of $v$, the inverse matrix won't change the length either.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=\operatorname{diag} (1,2)$, $v=(1,1)^T$, $w=(0,\sqrt{5})^T$, then
$\|Av\| = \|Aw\| = \sqrt{5}$, but
$\|A^{-1} v\| = \sqrt{5 \over 4}$, $\|A^{-1}w\| = \sqrt{5}$.